# How to install ruby-build for rbenv on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv, ruby-build

I installed rbenv. What is the easiest way to install ruby-build?

I've tried brew, but it displayed few errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clone as rbenv plugin using git**

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

**Upgrade with:**

```
git -C "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build pull
```